# Skip first iteration during forEach loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, foreach

How can I skip the first iteration in a forEach loop? I've got my forEach loop working as expected but I need to start on the second item totally ignoring the first item. I'm using ES6.

```
cars.forEach(car => {...do something});
```

I thought I could maybe do something like

```
cars.skip(1).forEach(car => {...do something});
```

Comment: You could use slice: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp

Comment: I got it! Thank you, set as new object before then use that for my input into the loop. Thanks again

Comment: Just use a regular `for` loop and start the index at `1` instead of `0`.  `.forEach()` is so yesterday.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you need to check index, and use return on that value, what you need. In your case you need to skip zero index (0), here is code

```
const cars = ['audi', 'bmw', 'maybach']

cars.forEach((car, index) => {
  if (index === 0) return;
  console.log(car)
});
```

this code will show 'bmw' and 'maybach'

Comment: There's no reason to do `return false` as `.forEach()` doesn't pay any attention to the return value.  Just do `if (index === 0) return;`.

Answer (score 5):

Writing out my comment as an answer:

```
cars.slice(1).forEach(car => { do something });
```

MDN reference to slice method: https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Answer (score 2):

Should be a fairly simple one-item test - your 'do something' function can set/read an external variable as required.

```js
let myArray = [1,2,3,4,5];

let firstItem = true;
myArray.forEach(item => {
  if (firstItem != true){
    console.log(item);
  } else {
    firstItem = false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

since there is counting variable available in forEach loop, you manually make one to count it.

```
let count = 0;
let skipVal = 0;
cars.forEach(car => {
count++;
if (count != skipVal){
...do something
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a **sliced for** loop?

```
const s=['car','bike','plane']
for(each of s.slice(1))console.log(each)
```